# jQuery: Last focused input field not populating as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list of variables and a list of fields, which may contain text inputs or textareas.  I want to click on a variable name and have it automatically append to the end of the content in the last focused input/textarea field (assuming the last thing that had focus was one of the those fields).

Here is a JsFiddle which illustrates what I'm trying to do: http://jsfiddle.net/fyUn6/

HTML:

```
Field 1: <input type="text" name="field[1]" /><br/>
Field 2: <input type="text" name="field[2]" /><br/>
Field 3: <input type="text" name="field[3]" /><br/>
Field 4: <textarea name="field[4]"></textarea><br/>
Field 5: <textarea name="field[5]"></textarea><br/>
<br/>
<span class="variable">NAME</span><br/>
<span class="variable">AGE</span><br/>
<span class="variable">WEIGHT</span><br/>
```

JavaScript:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    var prevFocus;

    jQuery("input[type=text], textarea").focus(function() {
        prevFocus = jQuery(this);
    });

    jQuery(".variable").click(function() {
        if(typeof prevFocus !== "undefined") {
            prevFocus.html(prevFocus.html()+jQuery(this).html());
        }
        else {
            alert("Select where you want to insert this variable first.");
        }
    });
});
```

Notice when you click a textarea (without typing in it first) then a variable, it populates correctly.  It does not do work for the input fields, however, nor when you start manually typing in the textarea then click a variable.

What's going on here?  Why is it working only under that one condition?  I'm sure I'm missing something simple, but I'm still new to jQuery and miss some of the finer points.

Comment: why not using append instead of html?

Comment: @AnkurAggarwal append will create more text nodes in text areas and create unexpected results. for changing the value of text fields and text areas, we should use `val()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, **[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shaun1ak/fyUn6/2/)**

prevFocus is a text input, **[val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/)** is what you need, and not **[html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)**.

```
if(typeof prevFocus !== "undefined") {
    prevFocus.val(prevFocus.val()+jQuery(this).html());
}
```

- **.val()** method is primarily used to get the values of form elements such as input, select  and textarea
- **.html()** is used to get the contents of any element

Answer (score 1):

Please try this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/fyUn6/5/)
There is slight change in your jquery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        var prevFocus;

        jQuery("input[type=text], textarea").focus(function() {
            prevFocus = jQuery(this);
        });



        jQuery(".variable").click(function() {
            if(typeof prevFocus !== "undefined") {
                prevFocus.val(prevFocus.html()+jQuery(this).html());
            }
            else {
                alert("Select where you want to insert this variable first.");
            }
        });
});
```